# SASL GSSAPI: ldap_sasl_interactive_bind : Other error (80) no credentials supplied

Tags: kerberos, openldap, gssapi

#### ldapsearch or ldapwhoami results in

```
# ldapwhoami
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible. (unknown mech-code 0 for mech unknown)
```

#### Setup:

- OpenLdap with SASL GSSAPI
- Kerberos KDC server (with the openLdap as the DB backend)
- I have a ticket cache created for `user1` to use for GSSAPI authentication.
- I have my krb5.keytab configured and set for the openLdap to use to authenticate with the KDC, as `ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM`

**ticket cache:**

```
# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user1@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
03/24/24 03:38:17  03/24/24 15:38:17  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 03/31/24 03:38:12
03/24/24 03:39:05  03/24/24 15:38:17  ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 03/31/24 03:38:12
```

**keytab:**

```
    klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab
    Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
    KVNO Principal
    ---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
       2 ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
       2 ldap/ldap.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue ended up being the file permissions on the `krb5.keytab` for openLdap to use.

My `slapd` was running using the `ldap` user. But the `ldap` user did not have read access to the `krb5.keytab` file, only the `root` user did.

Before:

```
# ls /etc/krb5.keytab -la
-rw-------    1 root     root           170 Mar 23 06:25 /etc/krb5.keytab
```

After:

```
# chmod 777 /etc/krb5.keytab
/ # ls /etc/krb5.keytab -la
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           170 Mar 23 06:25 /etc/krb5.keytab
```

After updating the file permission to give the `ldap` user read access, everything worked as expected! (777 probably wasn't necessary, I believe only read permission was needed.)

Successful GSSAPI authentication after:

```
# ldapwhoami -H ldap://ldap.example.com
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: user1@EXAMPLE.COM
SASL SSF: 56
SASL data security layer installed.
dn:uid=user1,cn=gssapi,cn=auth
```

Comment: No, ideally you shouldn't even be putting the 'ldap' keys in /etc/krb5.keytab at all – the system keytab should mostly have only 'host' and 'nfs' principals, while less-privileged services should have their own keytabs (specified via /etc/sasl2/slapd.conf or via `KRB5_KTNAME=`).